# AutoCompletetextView inside Activitygroup in Android

Tags: android

PopUpWindow's AutoCompleteTextView  which is inside ActivityGroup is giving android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generate your view/layout by program, instead of xml layout
  try:

```
AutoCompleteTextViewtextView yourView = new 　　AutoCompleteTextViewtextView(this.getParent() == null ? this : this.getParent());
```

Comment: But what you have suggested is not working and it is still throwing same error

Comment: do you dismiss your PopUpWindow onPause(and show it in onResume)?